# Flutter can not build a release apk

Tags: android, flutter, dart, apk

I run flutter `build apk --release`  everything works perfectly I run a debug apk and it works  but I got this problem while running a release apk

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                          386,9s (!)

    The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
    Building plugin audioplayers...
    Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...                         6,2s
    
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred configuring root project 'audioplayers'.
    > SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 5s
    
    The plugin audioplayers could not be built due to the issue above.
    Process finished with exit code 1
```

despite my project uses `AndroidX`  as the error said there is a problem with the package I unuse it the problem come with another and always the same problem until I delete all packages
I need some help

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to run the **--release** command when preparing an apk for release.
Just run this command assuming you have setup you build.gradle properly as per the documentation: (https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android)

```
flutter build apk
```

[EDIT]
Can you upload the entire log entry that you see. Except make sure increase the verbosity of the logs. So in this case:

```
flutter build apk -v
```

Then upload it to the thread. There is a package you are using that's not compatible with your current android version (minimum). What is the minimum Android SDK version you have set on your gradle.build file? Make sure to set to a number that all your packages will support. Depending on the package, but from my experience 21 was enough to cover the full spectrum.

Comment: the same problem

Comment: i add the log as an answer beczuse it's a little bit big  the sdk version is 21 from the beginning I already delete 4 packages and always the same problem I can not work this way

Comment: Write there is the issue: "SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an
ANDROID_HOME environment variable"

Comment: how i did not understand

Comment: You need to configure the Android SDK on your machine. Are you working on Windows or Mac OS? Please refer to the documentation and make sure that you have setup your machine first, before running a flutter compile: https://developer.android.com/studio/install

Comment: You are missing the SDK. Without the Android SDK installed or properly setup, you cannot compile. Please do some research on this, and then get back to me

Comment: If you are on Windows check your Environment Variables and check for ANDROID_HOME variable. Also run this command on terminal and check which version of Java you are using: java --version

Answer (score 0):

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

                    * What went wrong:
                    A problem occurred configuring root project 'audioplayers'.
                    > SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or
                    with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

                    * Try:
                    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option
                    to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

                    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

                    BUILD FAILED in 3s
[   +2 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'... (completed in 3,9s)
[   +2 ms] 
           FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
           
           * What went wrong:
           A problem occurred configuring root project 'audioplayers'.
           > SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an
ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
           
           * Try:
           Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get
more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
           
           * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
           
           BUILD FAILED in 3s
           
[  +10 ms] "flutter apk" took 184 621ms.
[   +8 ms] The plugin audioplayers could not be built due to the issue above.
[   +2 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
           #1      buildPluginsAsAar (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:848:7)
           #2      _asyncErrorWrapperHelper.errorCallback (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:91:64)
           #3      _rootRunBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1214:47)
           #4      _CustomZone.runBinary (dart:async/zone.dart:1107:19)
           #5      _FutureListener.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:157:20)
           #6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:708:47)
           #7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:729:24)
           #8      Future._completeError (dart:async/future_impl.dart:537:5)
           #9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:47:15)
           #10     buildGradleAar (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart)
           #11     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #12     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #13     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #14     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #15     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #16     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #17     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
           #18     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
           #19     _DefaultProcessUtils.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/process.dart)
           #20     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #21     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #22     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #23     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #24     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #25     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #26     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
           #27     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
           #28     _run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/error_handling_io.dart)
           #29     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #30     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #31     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #32     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #33     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #34     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #35     Future.wait.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:414:23)
           #36     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #37     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #38     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #39     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #40     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #41     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #42     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
           #43     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
           #44     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
           #45     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
           #46     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
           #47     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
           #48     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
           #49     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
           #50     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
           
           
[ +263 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 257ms
[   +6 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[   +1 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +1 ms] exiting with code 1
```